# Powershell If statement won't accept multiple OR conditions

Tags: windows, powershell, dns

I have a powershell script that processes a bunch of DNS A records and I'm trying to filter out the default records (i.e. "@", "ForestDNSZones", etc). Just trying this with a simple if statement doesn't seem to work.

Code sample:

```
$zoneARecords = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSserver -ZoneName $zoneName | ?{$_.RecordType -eq "A"}
foreach ($record in $zoneARecords) {
    $hostName = $record.HostName
    if ($hostName -ine "gc" -or "DomainDnsZones" -or "ForestDnsZones" -or "@") {
        # Do some stuff
    }
}
```

If I shorten it down to a single condition, it works but I want all conditions met:

```
if ($hostName -ine "gc")
```

If I expand out the statement so that each -or has explicit evaluations, it doesn't work:

```
if ($hostName -ine "gc" -or $hostName -ine "DomainDnsZones" -or $hostName -ine "ForestDnsZones" -or $hostName -ine "@") {
```

If I just use -ne, then it doesn't work for even a single record. I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple. I've tried trimming the string to exclude trailing spaces, but that didn't work either. String length matches what it should, so there's no extraneous space problems.

I've thought about nesting if statements, but that seems dumb. I have used the first example of chained -or conditions in other scripts without problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*I have used the first example of chained -or conditions in other scripts without problem.*" - you might want to revisit them, because they aren't doing what you think. `true OR true` is true, `false OR true` is true. Strings with content are true, so the test will never be false. `1 -eq 1 -or $true -or $true` and `0 -eq 1 -or $true -or $true` both -> True

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler the previous examples did evalulate to true regardless of which one was true. My mistake was in believing that this was using -ne instead of -eq in the other scripts. Thanks for pointing me to better understand this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `-and` to meet all conditions, and you must use the style of your second attempt where you have each comparison with its own left-hand operand:

```
if ($hostName -ine "gc" -and 
    $hostName -ine "DomainDnsZones" -and 
    $hostName -ine "ForestDnsZones" -and 
    $hostName -ine "@"
) { }
```

I would change it to use `-notcontains` or `-notin`:

```
if ("gc","DomainDnsZones","ForestDnsZones","@" -notcontains $hostname) { }
```

or

```
if ($hostname -notin "gc","DomainDnsZones","ForestDnsZones","@") { }
```

PowerShell is case-insensitive by default, but you can use `-inotcontains` or `-inotin` as well.

Comment: Could I create an array with the elements I want to avoid and use the -notcontains to catch all of them?

Comment: @McKenning absolutely! That's my preferred / recommended way of doing so. In fact, it is already using an array in my example, it just happens to be a literal array. Using one in a variable works great.